# Difference between invoke() and join() in ForkJoin framework in Scala

Tags: java, scala, fork-join

Scala [Example](https://fossies.org/dox/scala-2.11.7/classscala_1_1concurrent_1_1forkjoin_1_1RecursiveTask.html):

I know that `f2.compute()` waits until all subtasks are finished.
But what is the difference then to `join()?`
Is it anything related to the recursion?

Why is `compute()` on `f2` called directly and not via `f2.invoke()` ?

Would be very thankful for any explanations / source code hints.

[Java 7 RekursviveTask Source Code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html#RecursiveTask%28%29)

```
class Fibonacci extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {

    final int n;

    Fibonacci(int n) { this.n = n; }

    Integer compute() {

        if (n <= 1)

            return n;

        Fibonacci f1 = new Fibonacci(n - 1);

        f1.fork();

        Fibonacci f2 = new Fibonacci(n - 2);

        return f2.compute() + f1.join();

    }

}
```

Comment: here, the difference between `invoke` and `fork`is explained pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876144/fork-join-related-join-vs-get-vs-invoke

Comment: thx :) this post answered everything - besides "Why is compute() on f2 called directly and not via f2.invoke() ?"